# Is Firestore Local persistence available for Windows/

Tags: node.js, windows, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am running the following code:

```
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore  } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
const {firestore} = require("firebase-admin");
const QuerySnapshot = firestore.QuerySnapshot;

initializeApp()
const db = getFirestore();

const initializeListener = (collectionName) => {
console.log('called function');
const query = db.collection(collectionName);

query.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.docs().
    console.log('snapshot received');
    querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        console.log('doc change found');
        if (change.type === "added") {
            console.log("New " + collectionName, change.doc.data());
        }
    });
}, (erry) => {
    console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
});
}

initializeListener('my_collection');
```

If running whilst offline I don't see the 'snapshot received' message until I go online. If offline persistence should be available here, how do I access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Firebase Admin SDK (a wrapper around the Google Cloud backend SDK), which does not have any sort of persistence on any platform.  [Offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) is only available for the web and client SDKs provided by Firebase.  As you can see from the linked documentation:

> Note: Offline persistence is supported only in Android, Apple, and web apps.

Comment: Does this mean that even if I switched to the client SDK, this wouldn't work for Windows (other than as a web app)?

Comment: There is no client SDK for windows programs. Firebase is meant for web and mobile apps (iOS, Android).